# Fix links on curl page

Tags: php, curl

So after asking question after question people don't understand what I'm asking..

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mybroadband.co.za/news/');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Echo page back
echo $curl_response;

?>
```

Please run that script. In your address bar you'll see.. wwww.localhost/thisscriptname.php
Now click a link. Look at your address bar. It redirects to www.mybroadbank.co.za/xyz

I don't want it to redirect there. I want it to get the link contents via curl and to display it at www.localhost/thisscriptnameoranyname.php

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It gets the source fine. instead of `echo $curl_response;` paste this `echo '<textarea style="width:750px;height:500px;">'.$curl_response.'</textarea>';`

Comment: It means the content is being fetched right, there is no redirection. i tried it and the page was displayed fine, the problem is the links which you will have to edit or str_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the cURL Response brings all the html code from that URL and applies into your current page. Thus, all the links returned to your page are linked to the destination url (which is http://www.mybroadband.co.za/). That results in something like this in the response:

```
<a href="http://www.mybroadband.co.za/xyz">XYZ</a>
<a href="http://www.mybroadband.co.za/abc">ABC</a>
```

Thus, when you click on these links, it will direct you to `http://www.mybroadband.co.za/something`. What you need is not to be redirected into those pages, but instead display the content in your localhost page? Assuming that I'm right.

So, in order to solve this problem, you need to edit the cURL Response in which you **transform** those HTML anchor tags (links) above into:

```
<a onClick="getPage('http://www.mybroadband.co.za/xyz')">XYZ</a>
<a onClick="getPage('http://www.mybroadband.co.za/abc')">ABC</a>
```

Then just code a `getPage($link)` function in Javascript, using AJAX to request the page from $link and return, just like what you did.

Comment: Yay you understand what I'm asking! I know exactly what you mean but can you please write the code for me as I have no idea how to do it. Tried exactly what you've said before and it never worked..

Comment: Which part are you stuck at? Transforming or AJAX function?

Comment: Both parts to be honest. But if you help me with the transform part I understand the AJAX concept and can try that myself with google's help and come back if I'm stuck.

Comment: Yeah I think the AJAX part is easy too, you can find a lot of guides and demos on the Internet. About the first part, I'm afraid that it's complicated in order to write the whole algorithm. So if you think my reply helps, just tick on it and ask another question particularly related to solving this question. I think you may get a lot more in-depth instructions through that :)

Comment: What exactly am I asking? I've asked 3 questions related to this now and I've got nothing but what I already know I have to do. If I ask another question will you be able to write the algorithm?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at hiring someone to do this for you, if it's for an app you're selling. We're here to help, not do your job.

Comment: The problem with your questions so far is that it isn't clear enough, maybe I was lucky to understand that. So regarding to asking another question, you may need to ask something like: "How to transform anchor tags like this" (or something else) and carefully explain it, just like what I explained to you. Some real experts will come up with a regex solution which is more handy. I don't promise to answer it perfectly, but if I can, I will :)

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. Its not my app. Its open source and I just want to contribute. But its taking to long and its to hard so its all good I'm gonna stop

Answer (score 0):

To explain what's going on:
It does exactly what you want. *But* the browser interprets the HTML so you see the page. If you want to see the actual HTML code, then use `echo htmlspecialchars($curl_response);`. Putting it in a text area might not produce the correct results.

If you want to replace all links within the HTML code so that it stays on your page, then it's a whole different ballgame. You will need to parse the HTML code and replace them, using things like preg_replace and str_replace.

Comment: Yes, second bit. I understand you need to change all the urls and I can do that but no matter what I change them to those pages do not exist on on my site as the main page is called by curl. ALL the links need to be called by curl when clicked so they "exist"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<base>` tag from the header of the retrieved text. That's causing all the links to be based off the original site, not your proxied version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <base href="http://mybroadband.co.za/news/" />
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- remove this line
```

Though, if you're just blindly passing through the text without doing anything, you should probably just put this into an iframe and save the bandwidth on your server.

Comment: This won't work as when I click a link it goes somewhere that doesn't exist. Thanks though

Comment: You'd need to rewrite all the urls to point where you want, or add your own `<base>` definition. You're breaking the fundamental relationship between a site and a browser with your "proxy".

Comment: Instead of recreating the wheel, why not just install php-proxy? http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/  it'll do all that for you.

Comment: Because its a web app that I want to contribute to so it needs to be custom.