# Script to change all links on a page to curl requests

Tags: php, curl

I curled a page. So I now have the page showing on my domain. The links on that page all point to the original page. I need a script that takes all the  and replaces these links with the function

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL FROM THE A HREF OF THAT PARTICULAR LINK');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_response;
```

So when the links are clicked it does not direct you to the original page but runs the curl function and takes you to that page.

P.S thanks for the edit was about to do it but you got there first.

Comment: why not just do a string replace on $curl_response before you echo it

Comment: And what about all the fine answers [you've already gotten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032676/fix-links-on-curl-page)?

Comment: Can you string replace a url with a function and in that function use the original url

Comment: None of the answers have gotten me any closer.. I just keep getting told the same thing but nothing that actually works

Comment: Did the answer with the open source proxy help?

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to write a proxy? This has already been done, and [open source](http://www.google.com/search?q=open%20source%20php%20proxy).

You'll be wanting to make replacements on $curl_response. If the page uses relative paths, you could just append `<base href="http://yourdomain.com" />` to the `<head>`. In addition, you could `str_replace('http://theirdomain.com/', '')` to remove any absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comments, the missing part you may be looking for could be PHP's [DOM extension](http://php.net/dom), or comparable. Basically, you want to parse the HTML of the page you're cURLing, so you can alter it.

You can do this by telling cURL to return the page source to you as a string (as you are doing), then feed it to [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). You would then grab all links using [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) (supplying `'a'`, possibly `'img'` and a few others, as per your discretion).

Once you have that [DOMNodeList](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), you can then alter their `href`-Attributes by retrieving the attribute with `...->attributes->getNamedItem('href')` (that would be `src` for images, of course, if you want to go that far), tweaking the contents using the attribute's `...->nodeValue`, e.g.:

```
$attributeNode->nodeValue = myURLtransform($attribute->nodeValue);
```

Finally, you would use [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to have the altered code, which you can then `echo`.

Comment: When I tweak the contents can I change links to be curl calls?

Comment: That depends. If the page you get the original page on is `mypage.php?url=url-encoded-url` e.g. `mypage.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`, then your `myURLtransform()` would look like this: `function myURLtransform($url) { return 'mypage.php?url=' . urlencode($url); }`. Alternatively, if you want to cURL the pages and put them somewhere else, you would have something like `function myURLtransform($url) { /* cURL call, then save retrieved page to a file with e.g. file_put_contents() */ return 'url-to-that-file'; }`, though that would be arbitrarily slow for arbitrarily many links.

Comment: The link address would look similar to this http://192.168.0.14:8081/home/displayShow?show=94991

I have index.php that looks like this http://pastebin.com/RMzPJj01

It then has links on it that all look similar to  http://192.168.0.14:8081/home/displayShow?show=94991

I need it to take those links and transform them so when yo click on them it curls the link. Please could you code that for me..